# Azure DevOps pipeline using DockerCompose pushing image to DockerHub

Tags: azure, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I have setup an azure-pipeline.yml for my React/NodeJS project on Azure DevOps. The code is in GitHub and the image is being pushed to reside in DockerHub.

My azure-pipeline.yml file is:

```
trigger:
  - development

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  dockerhubNS: 'myDockerHub'
  ImageNames: 'myDockerImageName'
  ImageTag: 'demo_all'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build image
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - task: DockerCompose@0
            displayName: Build an image
            inputs:
              projectName: $(dockerhubNS)/$(ImageNames)
              containerregistrytype: Container Registry
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: portal_demo
              action: Run a Docker Compose command
              dockerComposefile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/docker-compose.yml'
              dockerComposeCommand: build node
              qualifyImageNames: true
              buildImages: true
              additionalImagetags: $(ImageTag)
          - task: DockerCompose@0
            displayName: Push an image
            inputs:
              projectName: $(dockerhubNS)/$(ImageNames)
              containerregistrytype: Container Registry
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: portal_demo
              action: Push services
              dockerComposefile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/docker-compose.yml'
              includeSourceTags: true
              includeLatestTag: true
              qualifyImageNames: true
```

I have setup the service container in Azure DevOps as 'portal_demo' using the instructions given at:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-build-deploy-azure-pipelines?tabs=java-script
```

My issues are:

a) The "tag" is not working and I am unable to tag the docker image to the name I want it to be (*myDockerHub/myDockerImageName:demo_all*)

b) The commands to push to the DockerHub is not working and even when I use the tag/image name created by the build step, it does not push it to the required repo. It fails saying:

```
/usr/bin/docker push hub.docker.com/***/myDockerImageName:demo_all

The push refers to repository [hub.docker.com/***/myDockerImageName]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: hub.docker.com/***/myDockerImageName
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: hub.docker.com/***/myDockerImageName
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Push image to dockerhub registry
```

Any help on what I need to modify on my pipeline commands to get this to work?

Links I have checked:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops

https://codingcanvas.com/using-docker-compose-in-azure-devops-pipeline/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops
```